# Is IntelliJ has line move shortcut like Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, intellij-idea, shortcut

Typically, I'm using Visual Studio(including code). but some cases, It necessary that use IntelliJ.
I want to Line cut/paste shortcut like Visual Studio to support.

you can move line that has carret to upper line, if you use the Alt+Up in Visual Studio.(and Alt+Down use to move downer line)

Is IntelliJ support these shortcut like Visual Studio that I describe you?

How to set it?

Comment: sorry, I mistake. Not Ctrl, It Alt+Up and Down. with Ctrl is Scrolling line by line.

Comment: Hi min you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69422749/edit) your question and change it.

Comment: In IntelliJ menu goto `Help->Keymap Reference` you will get the key mapping for most used actions.

Answer (score 3):

In the Code menu there are the actions `Move Line Up` and `Move Line Down` to move text lines up and down (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> respectively on all platforms I believe).